# SQL Inner join table matching rows count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have sql query like this

```
 select fname,lname,Id from Employee e
 inner join Address a on e.Id=a.EmployeeId
```

what I also want to include in the select list is, number of rows in address table that match with every row in employee table.

For Example.

If Employee With FNAme mandar has two address rows then in select i should see

Mandar J 1 2

I am aware i could do this with groupby but i am thinking if it's the ideal way of doing it to only get count of matching rows. subquery is probably not good for performance.

```
select fname,lname,Id,count(a.Id) from Employee e
inner join Address a on e.Id=a.EmployeeId
groupby a.EmployeeId
```

then i also have to include `fname,lname , Id in the 
   groupby` list, which is probably not clean.

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the columns you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions. In your case do: `GROUP BY fname,lname,Id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `COUNT` as an analytic function:

```
SELECT
    e.fname,
    e.lname,
    e.Id,
    COUNT(a.EmployeeId) OVER (PARTITION BY e.Id) AS cnt
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN Address a
    ON e.Id = a.EmployeeId
```

The above call to `COUNT` will return the number of address records for each employee partition.

Edit: We should probably be counting `a.EmployeeId` because we would expect a zero count should a given employee happen to have no addresses.